# How do I maximize window after I've minimize them?

Tags: keyboard

I'm a new Mac user and I regularly minimize windows using the <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> shortcut. Is there a keyboard shortcut to restore these windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I know of is to get into Exposé mode (e.g. press (<kbd>fn</kbd> +) <kbd>F3</kbd> on newer keyboards) and then pressing the down arrow key. You will see the currently selected minimised window (in the lower third of the screen) surrounded by a blue shadow and you can select other windows by moving around with the arrow keys. You can then bring any window to the foreground by hitting <kbd>return</kbd>.

Answer (score 5):

beside [Asmus](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/11527/how-to-maximize-after-minimize/11531#11531) Solution you can use <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> to find your minimize software's windows after you go on select windows hold <kbd>option</kbd> and release all the key.

Comment: That's what I use. Sad it doesn't go for multi-window apps (like browsers or document apps).

Comment: I'm curious how to do this `cmd+tab` and then `option`.  I'm on Mavericks and it didn't do anything for me, so it could be that it no longer works on this OS.  But I'm not clear what you mean by "go on select windows" @Am1rr3zA and @Eimantas, so I might not be doing it right.  Please give some more details.

Comment: @RobBednark When doing cmd+tab, go to the app's icon you want to restore and while holding cmd press option. After option is pressed - release cmd.

Comment: Doesn't work if there are multiple windows of an application collapsed under one icon, say multiple VScode windows