# How do I disable the shortcut "Command+M" which minimizes a window in Chrome in Monterey?

Tags: keyboard, google-chrome, shortcut

It's really annoying that <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd> will minimize my current Chrome window. I want to disable it but couldn't find the way. Can somebody help?

I tried to Google it, finding this [post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/115562/how-do-i-disable-the-minimize-command-m-shortcut-in-mavericks) but it seems not working in 2022.

I also went through Chrome's settings, but can't find anything related to shortcuts.

Comment: What happens when you assign the shortcut in System Preferences? What does the Windows menu look like (shortcuts are shown in the menu). Have you tried assigning the shortcut to ALL applications, rather than Chrome?